# Joining tables containing comma delimited values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have three excel sheet I push them into tables in SQL server and I need to join these table. However, I believe - as I have tried already - normal join wouldn't work. I have programming background but not that much with SQL.

```
Table1

ID  Data_column reference_number
1   some data   1528,ss-456
2   some data   9523
3   some data   ss-952
4   some data   null

Table2 

ID      Data_column
ss-456  some data
ss-952  some data


Table3 

ID      Data_column
1528    some data
9523    some data
```

In the case below How I will be able to join this raw on both table.

```
Table1

ID  Data_column reference_number
1   some data   1528,ss-456
```

Comment: Why does the column `reference_number` have multiple entries ? First, normalize the table.

Comment: unfortunately, yes

Comment: Cannot it be split into multiple rows?

Comment: What are the rules set for reference_number? Is it always xxxx,yy-zzz ? You could write a quick and dirty script to join on part of the columns but that is not efficient. The real solution is to split the comma seperated values into multiple columns.

Comment: do you mean no solution for this case

Comment: Yes, I know The real solution is to split the comma, However, I still need the quick and dirty script to join on part of the columns even if it is not efficient.

Comment: Which SQL Server version do you use?

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @t1 as table(
     id int
    ,data_column varchar(20)
    ,reference_number varchar(20)
)

declare @t2 as table(
     id varchar(20)
    ,data_column varchar(20)
)

declare @t3 as table(
     id varchar(20)
    ,data_column varchar(20)
)

insert into @t1 values(1,'some data','1528,ss-456'),(2,'some data','9523'),(3,'some data','ss-952'),(4,'some data',null);

insert into @t2 values('ss-456','some data'),('ss-952','some data');

insert into @t3 values(1528,'some data'),(9523,'some data');
```

Quick solution

```
select * from @t1 t1
left outer join @t2 t2 on t1.reference_number like '%'+t2.id or t1.reference_number like t2.id+'%'
left outer join @t3 t3 on t1.reference_number like '%'+t3.id or t1.reference_number like t3.id+'%'
```

Result (left join):

```
id  data_column reference_number    id      data_column id  data_column
1   some data   1528,ss-456         ss-456  some data   1528    some data
2   some data   9523                NULL    NULL        9523    some data
3   some data   ss-952              ss-952  some data   NULL    NULL
4   some data   NULL                NULL    NULL        NULL    NULL
```

You can change 'left outer join' to 'inner join' for exact match.

Comment: Change reference_number in first row from `1528,ss-456` to `1528,ss-456shouldnotmatch` and watch what happens.

Comment: I change and result is same. What happens to wait?

Comment: It will match `ss-456shouldnotmatch` with `ss-456` which is incorrect.

Comment: @SalmanA I got your point and fix the query. It works if there is only two referances.

Answer (score 1):

Clumsy design, clumsy solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON ',' + Table1.reference_number + ',' LIKE '%,' + Table2.ID + ',%'
INNER JOIN Table3 ON ',' + Table1.reference_number + ',' LIKE '%,' + Table3.ID + ',%'
```

You ***must*** append leading and trailing commas to make sure that, for example,  `1528,ss-456asdf` does not match `%ss-456%`.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems here. First is the inconsistent type of ID in table 2 and 3 and aggregation of referenced keys in table 1. Here is an example how to solve both problems. To split REFERENCE_NUMBER column I used STRING_SPLIT function.

Update:
I added the solution which should work with SQL Server 2012.

I assumed that you wish to join data from table 1 with 2 or 3 depending in existence of this data. This is just my idea what you wanted to achive.

```
-- data preparing
declare @t1 as table(
     id int
    ,data_column varchar(20)
    ,reference_number varchar(20)
)

declare @t2 as table(
     id varchar(20)
    ,data_column varchar(20)
)

declare @t3 as table(
     id int
    ,data_column varchar(20)
)

insert into @t1 values(1,'some data','1528,ss-456'),(2,'some data','9523'),(3,'some data','ss-952'),(4,'some data',null);

insert into @t2 values('ss-456','some data'),('ss-952','some data');

insert into @t3 values(1528,'some data'),(9523,'some data');

-- Solution example version >= 2016
with base as (
select t1.id,t1.data_column,f1.value from @t1 t1 outer apply string_split(t1.reference_number,',') f1)
select b.id,b.data_column,b.value,t2.data_column from base b join @t2 t2 on b.value = t2.id
union all
select b.id,b.data_column,b.value,t3.data_column from base b join @t3 t3 on try_cast(b.value as int ) = t3.id
union all
select b.id,b.data_column,b.value,null from base b where b.value is null;

-- Solution for SQL Version < 2016
with base as (
select t1.id,t1.data_column,f1.value from @t1 t1 outer apply( 
    SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') value
FROM
(
    SELECT CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(t1.reference_number, ',', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS String
) AS A
CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/X') AS Split(a)
) f1)
select b.id,b.data_column,b.value,t2.data_column from base b join @t2 t2 on b.value = t2.id
union all
select b.id,b.data_column,b.value,t3.data_column from base b join @t3 t3 on try_cast(b.value as int ) = t3.id
union all
select b.id,b.data_column,b.value,null from base b where b.value is null;
```

Comment: `STRING_SPLIT` is valid only from version 2016.

Comment: Please mention where this f1 come from 
select t1.id,t1.data_column,f1.value from @t1 t1 outer apply string_split(t1.reference_number,',') f1)

Comment: AsRa thanks for the comment. When I started to add my solution there was no info about version ;) Mustafa Alqanbar I added version which should work in SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

You will require a function to divide the comma separated sting into rows. If you don't have access to thr inbuilt [string_split() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (as of mssql 2017 with compatibility of 130) there are several to choose from [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1(
>    ID               INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
>   ,Data_column      VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
>   ,reference_number VARCHAR(11)
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table1(ID,Data_column,reference_number) VALUES
>   (1,'t1somedata','1528,ss-456')
> , (2,'t1somedata','9523')
> , (3,'t1somedata','ss-952')
> , (4,'t1somedata',NULL);
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table2(
>    ID           VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
>   ,Data_column VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table2(ID,Data_column) VALUES
>  ('ss-456','t2somedata'),
>  ('ss-952','t2somedata');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table3(
>    ID           VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
>   ,Data_column VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table3(ID,Data_column) VALUES 
> ('1528','t3somedata'),
> ('9523','t3somedata');
> ```

I have used this splistring function, but you can use almost any of the many freely available.

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_Moden
> (
>    @List NVARCHAR(MAX),
>    @Delimiter NVARCHAR(255)
> )
> RETURNS TABLE
> WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
> RETURN
>   WITH E1(N)        AS ( SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
>                          UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
>                          UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),
>        E2(N)        AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b),
>        E4(N)        AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b),
>        E42(N)       AS (SELECT 1 FROM E4 a, E2 b),
>        cteTally(N)  AS (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@List,1))) 
>                          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E42),
>        cteStart(N1) AS (SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t
>                          WHERE (SUBSTRING(@List,t.N,1) = @Delimiter OR t.N = 0))
>   SELECT Item = SUBSTRING(@List, s.N1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@List,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000))
>     FROM cteStart s;
> ```

This is what the data looks like using the splitstring function:

> ```
> select *
> from table1
> cross apply SplitStrings_Moden(reference_number,',')
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | Data_column | reference_number | Item  
> -: | :---------- | :--------------- | :-----
>  1 | t1somedata  | 1528,ss-456      | 1528  
>  1 | t1somedata  | 1528,ss-456      | ss-456
>  2 | t1somedata  | 9523             | 9523  
>  3 | t1somedata  | ss-952           | ss-952
>  4 | t1somedata  | null             | null
> ```

and now joining to the other tables:

> ```
> select
> *
> from (
> select *
> from table1
> cross apply SplitStrings_Moden(reference_number,',')
> ) t1
> left join table2 on t1.item = table2.id
> left join table3 on t1.item = table3.id
> where t1.item is not null
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | Data_column | reference_number | Item   | ID     | Data_column | ID   | Data_column
> -: | :---------- | :--------------- | :----- | :----- | :---------- | :--- | :----------
>  1 | t1somedata  | 1528,ss-456      | 1528   | null   | null        | 1528 | t3somedata 
>  1 | t1somedata  | 1528,ss-456      | ss-456 | ss-456 | t2somedata  | null | null       
>  2 | t1somedata  | 9523             | 9523   | null   | null        | 9523 | t3somedata 
>  3 | t1somedata  | ss-952           | ss-952 | ss-952 | t2somedata  | null | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=02d130e011a98ca9e2b2aa0d5f9cb532)*

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS:** If your `reference_number` is fixed and always stored IDs upto 2 only then you can go with the below approach

```
SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT ID, 
        data_column, 
        CASE WHEN PATINDEX ( '%,%', reference_number) > 0 THEN 
            SUBSTRING(reference_number, PATINDEX ( '%,%', reference_number)+1, LEN(reference_number)) 
        ELSE reference_number END AS ref_col
    FROM @table1
    UNION
    SELECT ID, 
        data_column, 
        CASE WHEN PATINDEX ( '%,%', reference_number) > 0 THEN 
            SUBSTRING(reference_number, 0, PATINDEX ( '%,%', reference_number)) 
        END
    FROM @table1) t1
LEFT JOIN @table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.ref_col
LEFT JOIN @table3 t3 ON t3.id = t1.ref_col
WHERE t1.ref_col IS NOT NULL
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
ID  data_column ref_col ID      Data_column ID      Data_column
1   some data   1528    NULL    NULL        1528    some data
1   some data   ss-456  ss-456  some data   NULL    NULL
2   some data   9523    NULL    NULL        9523    some data
3   some data   ss-952  ss-952  some data   NULL    NULL
4   some data   null    NULL    NULL        NULL    NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Implement and get desired result using `Substring` and `charIndex` functions on the `reference_number`.

I upvoted an answer of 'is_oz' since i used his ready made schema to test and build a query for you.

below is the final query i build after [several tries i made here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a090979ea471156cd5b2d829cb50223b):

```
select * from abc
left join abc2 on abc2.id = case when charindex(',',abc.reference_number) > 0
                             then substring(abc.reference_number
                                       ,charindex(',',abc.reference_number)+1
                                       ,len(abc.reference_number)-(charindex(',',abc.reference_number)-1)
                                      ) 
                             else abc.reference_number
                             end
left join abc3 on abc3.id = case when charindex(',',abc.reference_number) > 0
                             then substring(abc.reference_number
                                       ,0
                                       ,(charindex(',',abc.reference_number))
                                      ) 
                             else abc.reference_number
                             end
```

As per your requirement as much as i understand, it is returning all the matched rows from 2 other tables but still i hope this fulfills all the requirements you seek in your question. :)